# Lens stuck on enlarger board/mount

Tags: lens, enlarging

I have a LPL VC7700 VCCE 6x7 enlarger with two Nikon El-Nikkor lenses (50 and 80) that I could easily interchange up until yesterday. Now the 80mm lens is stuck on the lensboard : when I try and unscrew it, the lens rotates fine but keeps clicking and never catches the screw thread.
Any suggestions other than buying another lensboard?
[image]

Comment: It sounds like the treads (of either the lens or the mount) are stripped. Try lifting gently on the lens as you unscrew it, this may get past the stripped area and allow good thread to meet good thread to start unscrewing. If/when you get it unscrewed, carefully inspect the threads on both the lens & mount to see which are stripped and see about getting them repaired (it may just take the careful application of a small file) or replaced.